# @RequestMapping Not Working For Trailing Slash In Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using spring 4.2.2 jars. Below isn't working for me.
**index.jsp**

```
<form action="./abc/">
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Below is my controller class.

```
package pank.spring.test;
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class Hello{
    @RequestMapping("/abc/")
    public String printOnPage(ModelMap mp) {
        mp.addAttribute("msg", "akash");
        return "success";
    }
}
```

In web.xml below mapping for DispatcherServlet

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>xyz</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

In *-servlet.xml file

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="pank.spring.test"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

I can see here **RequestMappingHandlerMapping** is being registered. But I am gettting 404. **Note: But while in **index.jsp** I am using `<form action="./abc">` and In Hello controller I am using `@RequestMapping("/abc")` then it's  working fine.Not sure why.

Comment: remove the class level @RequestMapping annotation

Comment: @AbdullahKhan Thanks, But unfortunately removing this annotation, also doesn't work. By the way can you please explore why you suggested to remove this annotation from class level or can you please share any link where I can understand this. Sorry for dumb question but It's important for me. Thanks again